# Visual Studio TypeScript intellisense with double underscore

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm having trouble with VS2013 (Update 4) getting the intellisense/auto-complete to work for variables prefixed with double underscore `__`. Take the example below:

`var __MYVAR: string;`

When I start typing `__MYVAR` it gets picked up by intellisense as having an additional underscore (i.e. `___MYVAR`). If I choose to use the auto-complete, it will insert the incorrect `___MYVAR`, and VS will proceed to yell at me because `___MYVAR` doesn't exist.

**NOTE**: This also breaks the reference finding in VS on all variables/functions (including variables/functions defined on a class) prefaced with double underscore.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I would appreciate any feedback, as this is an incredibly frustrating problem I've been having.

**EDIT**: Note that this only started happening with VS2013 after update 4.

**EDIT2**: Here is a list of my installed plugins:

- Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
- Azure Resource Manager Tools
- Behaviors SDK
- Microsoft Advertising pubCenter Service
- Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8.1
- Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8.1 XAML
- **Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools**
- Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools For Visual Studio
- Microsoft Azure Quickstarts
- Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC5 Scaffolding
- NuGet
- Regex Tester
- TroutZoom
- Visual F#
- Visual FSharp Tools Templates for VSPro
- **Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4**
- Windows Phone 8.1 SDK Integration

I have highlighted the plugins that seem relevant. I tried disabling Web Essentials, but it didn't solve the issue. There is no way to disable ASP.NET and Web Tools, you have to uninstall it from Programs & Features. Unfortunately I have no idea what I have to uninstall in Programs & Features in order to remove the plugin.

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior in VS 2013 Professional Update 4.  Do you have ReSharper or a similar add-on installed?  If so, try disabling the add-ons temporarily and see if it still happens.

Comment: I will try disabling some add-ons, the only thing I am running that I would think has an impact is Web Essentials.

Comment: Web Essentials is not the issue, and I don't have too many other plugins that are able to be disabled without uninstalling something from my programs. @NYCdotNet, can you compare your installed plugins with the list I provide in my edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug :

[image]

Happens in the playground as well [TSPlay](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20__MYVAR%3A%20string%3B%0A__)

I have created an issue report : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1548

Comment: Good to know, thanks! This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

As Basarat stated, this was a bug in 1.3. It appears to be fixed for what will be our 1.4 release.

If this is causing major problems, you can check out our `release-1.4` branch in the TypeScript repo. It should be stable. Simply swap out the language service [as I have described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1110#issuecomment-62451204). Remember to exercise caution and ***back up your old tsc.js and typescriptServices.js*** if you do choose to do so.